# Xmlreader movetoelement with PHP

Tags: php, xmlreader

I have to analyzed big xml file, more than 2,1gb.

I proceed with Php, Xmlreader and automated tasks to do the update every day.

My server is restricted and the automated tasks are restricted for an hour.

2,1gb in one hour is impossible and i can't change my server for the moment.

So I record on my database the last number of the product and whe come the second update, next hour, I compare the last number record with the new read by xmlreader. If the number is the same i proceed to the update else (php distortion) i move to the next node and I wait for the last number.

Is it possible, when come to the second update to go more quickly and easily to the last number of the node updated ?

The actualy system work but have to read the file and take time to find the last product number save.

I don't speak a very well english so I expect that you will understand.

A part of the Xml File :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PRODUITS>

  <PRODUIT id="1">

    <CAPACITE>4</CAPACITE>

    <LOGEMENT><![CDATA[Résidence]]></LOGEMENT>

    <HEBERGEMENT><![CDATA[Studio 4 personnes]]></HEBERGEMENT>

    <REGION><![CDATA[Alpes du Nord]]></REGION>

    <PAYS><![CDATA[France]]></PAYS>

    <CODEPOSTAL>73500</CODEPOSTAL>
  </PRODUIT>

  <PRODUIT id="2">

    <CAPACITE>4</CAPACITE>

    <LOGEMENT><![CDATA[Résidence]]></LOGEMENT>

    <HEBERGEMENT><![CDATA[Studio 4 personnes]]></HEBERGEMENT>

    <REGION><![CDATA[Alpes du Nord]]></REGION>

    <PAYS><![CDATA[France]]></PAYS>

    <CODEPOSTAL>73500</CODEPOSTAL>
  </PRODUIT>

  <PRODUIT id="3">

    <CAPACITE>4</CAPACITE>

    <LOGEMENT><![CDATA[Résidence]]></LOGEMENT>

    <HEBERGEMENT><![CDATA[Studio 4 personnes]]></HEBERGEMENT>

    <REGION><![CDATA[Alpes du Nord]]></REGION>

    <PAYS><![CDATA[France]]></PAYS>

    <CODEPOSTAL>73500</CODEPOSTAL>
  </PRODUIT>
</PRODUITS>
```

My System of analysis in PHP :

**How can I go to product ID 3 directly?**

```
<?php
if(file_exists("$file_xml"))
{
  $reader = new XMLReader();
  $reader->open("$file_xml");

  while($reader->read())
  {
    if( ($reader->name === 'PRODUIT') && ($reader->nodeType==XMLReader::ELEMENT) )
    {
    $node = new SimpleXMLElement($reader->readOuterXML());


    $id= mysql_real_escape_string(utf8_decode($node['id']));

          // For the next update but TAKE TIME !!
          if( ($num!="3") ) 
      {
      // Nothing to do
          }
      else
      { 
      $num = mysql_real_escape_string(utf8_decode($node['num']));
          ....                          
      }
    }
   }
$reader->close();
}
```

?>

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with XMLReader my self but this should work

```
if( ($reader->nodeType==XMLReader::ELEMENT) && ($reader->name === 'PRODUIT'))
{
  if($reader->getAttribute('id') === 3){
    //id is 3
  }
}
```